# Getting a string from EditText

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I'm trying to get the the text written by the user in an edittext view and store it in a String value then set this String value in a class that I created that contains two String Objects but when I run the code it gives me an error with a null pointer exception because the "WrittenSubj" and "WrittenDeta" are equal to null, how can i solve this problem?

```
public class TaskDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText WrittenSubj;
EditText WrittenDeta;
Button SaveBut;
TheTask theTask;
private Database database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_details);
    WrittenSubj=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.thesubject);
    WrittenDeta=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.theDetails);
    SaveBut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);

    String subj=WrittenSubj.getText().toString();
    String deta=WrittenDeta.getText().toString();
    theTask.setSubject(subj);
    theTask.setDetails(deta);

}
```

Comment: too old question .

Comment: what is `TheTask `

Comment: have not initialized "theTask" variable.

Comment: It is not because the editText are null. "theTask" will be null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Note: I'm still a beginner to android studio and to stackoverflow. "TheTask" is a class that i created that contains two strings objects

Answer (score 1):

I think TheTask is your Beam class, And you have not initialize it.

Initialize this.

```
theTask = new TheTask();
```

And use

```
theTask.setSubject(subj);
theTask.setDetails(deta);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the TheTask class before using that like below

```
TheTask theTask = new TheTask();
```

And after that use object of theTask like below

```
theTask.setSubject(subj);
theTask.setDetails(deta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is arrising because you are initializing edittexts and getting its text `getText()` in method `onCreate()` and `OnCreate()` is the method called when activity is created So at the time of creation of activity your edit texts will obviously be having null/empty value.
So you must call `edittext.getText()` on any event click or button click after actually the text have entered.